# Azure SQL - Bulk load from Blob storage not working (file could not be opened)

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to bulk load data from an Azure Blob Storage into an Azure SQL database. It fails with the following message:

> Error SQL72014: Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 162 Cannot bulk load because the file "proj/books/AUTHORS.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 12007(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).

The container name is `proj`, and it has a folder (which contains a file). They are, `books` and `AUTHORS.csv`, respectively. All the objects exists, and I've been trying different access levels (Private, Blob and Container).

The loading is done through Azure DevOps pipelines. I'd say that on DB's side, everything is fine. The pipeline, for instance, can access the DB and performs a couple of tests (if certain tables exists, and so on). Actually, the tables are created by the same pipeline that is supposed to load the data.

I found many questions regarding a similar problem (for instance, [link to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56081631/how-to-correct-operating-system-error-code-12007-when-accessing-azure-blob-sto)). However, in those cases, the *Reason* was different.

Any ideas or suggestions?

**EDIT 1:**

To be honest, I'm right now, more or less, in those kind of situations in which "everything just started working fine". I must say "more or less" because one change did happen.

The original blob storage name had "-" and "_" characters. Something like, my-blob_dev_env. The name was created using Terraform plans, and no problem raised. Anyways, other resources was also being created with such characters, but Terraform complained about the "-". For instance, Azure Storage Account.

Besides that, I tried to use Azure Data Studio to run SQL queries against the DB. At the moment, I received error messages complaining about the "-" in the DB name. I was able to connect to server, and run queries that didn't mention explicitly the DB name. However, I was not able to insert rows.

Thus, I changed the Terraform plans, so that the DB name doesn't have anymore "-" characters. The "_" is still there, and poses no problem.

After doing it, I could bulk insert all the data.

Comment: Could you please show what you were doing, for example, yaml definition, script?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to Reproduce your scenario in my environment and ended up with similar error as below:

[image]

After researching on error and checking the code I found that I entered the **wrong URL of blob storage account**
After changing It I could be able to load data from Azure Blob Storage into an Azure SQL database.

**My code:**

```sql
# Create a MASTER KEY
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD='superStrongPassword!2';

# Create Scoped credential
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL mcred
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'SAS Access Token';

# Create external data source
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE sampledataset
WITH 
(
    TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
    LOCATION = 'https://Storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net',
    CREDENTIAL = mcred
); 

# bulk load data
SET NOCOUNT ON
 BULK INSERT dbo.ABCD --Table to insert data into
 FROM 'demo/2021/04/05/ABCD_050420211200.csv' --Location of the file [containername/folders/filename]
     WITH (
      DATA_SOURCE = 'sampledataset' 
      ,DATAFILETYPE = 'char' 
      ,FIELDTERMINATOR = ',' 
      ,ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' 
      ,BATCHSIZE=100000 
      ,TABLOCK 
       )


Select * from dbo.ABCD;
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Does the DB name has non-alphanumeric characters? I just edited my question so that it reflects what I found when removing "-" characters from the DB name.